# Open a large pdf file

Tags: pdf

I have a large PDF file (3.67 GB). I need some pages of this file. If it could be opened I would get a screenshot of those pages. But the problem is that it needs more memory to be opened. I tried different ways like breaking the pdf or viewing the pdf from server but I was not successful. Would you please let me know if there would be a way to open this large file?

Thanks

Comment: What is your current code to open it that results in out of memory problems?

Comment: @Alejandro When I directly open the pdf it says out of memory, but I used xdg-open in linux and it did not work. I tried to open it in Chrome and save one page as pdf but it did not open in Chrome too. Thanks.

Comment: @K J: the pdf file was built by a program in linux and it includes 23 figures only. This is a result of scientific research which is about clustering. If I had have option to make it small I would have done that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do you know the page number? If so, you can try the `pdftocairo` command from the poppler utils to extract single pages as image.

Comment: If it is an option for you, consider using something like the LEADTOOLS toolkit (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor). Which offers means to optimize loading of large PDF files as images, which is detailed [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/to/using-the-optimizedload-functions-to-speed-loading-large-files.html).